# How to create multiple array based on row of .CSV file in Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, csv

I am implementing Angular template for reading .CSV file and generating table. So I created two .CSV file, one for the header and second one for the table content.

**For heading CSV file: header.csv**

[image]

**For data of table CSV file: tableContent.csv**

[image]

Now I am able to read all data and converted into array, But I am getting into one array. I am sharing my code for more understanding.I have putted .csv file in assets folder.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'project';
  myData: any;
  myContent: any;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClient.get('assets/header.csv', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.myData = data.split("\n");
      }
    );
  }
  clicked(event) {
    console.log(event.srcElement.name);
    this.httpClient.get('assets/tableContent.csv', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.myContent = data.split(",");
        let ab=this.myContent;
        console.log("------------>",ab);        
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let dataheader of myData"><button (click)="clicked($event)" id={{dataheader}} name={{dataheader}}>{{dataheader}}</button></th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Browser screen**
[image]

I want to create multiple object of array. like below:

```
[{
"myAccess":["myAccess","Prod","URL","a@gmail.com","Enable"]
},
{
"System":["System","Environment","URL","a@gmail.com","Enable"]
},
{
"OAM":["OAM","DEV","URL","test@gmail.com","Enable"]
},
{
"Mylogin":["Mylogin","prod","URL","s@gmail.com","Enable"]
}]
```

> Table heading will comes from particular header.csv and data will comes from
>   tableContent.csv. So Finally If i will click on the particular header
>   so It will search into json object(which is read by tablecontent.csv).
>   will show the particular result. Like if I will click on the myAccess
>   so related myaccess data show in the table data.

Thanks in advance, Kindly share your idea.

Comment: What is the reason to split headers and data in to 2 files ?

Comment: @SupunDeSilva Thanks for the comment. Actually Header will comes from header.csv and data will comes from tableContent.csv. So Finally If i will click on the particular header so It will search into json object(which is read by tablecontent.csv). will show the particular result. Like if I will click on the myAccess so related myaccess data show in the table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem. Please handle errors better than me :D (Bootstrap being used for styling)

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FileService } from './services/file.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'temp-app';

  public headers = [];
  public data = {};

  public selectedHeader = null;
  constructor(private fileSvc: FileService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fileSvc.getHeaders().subscribe(
      data =>  {
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
          let headers = data.split('\n');
          headers = headers.filter(x => x.trim() !== '');
          for (const item of headers) {
            this.headers.push(item.trim());
          }
        } else {
          this.headers = [];
        }
      }
    );

    this.fileSvc.getData().subscribe(
      data =>  {
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
          const tempData = data;
          let rows = [];
          rows = tempData.split('\n');
          for (let row of rows) {
            if (row.trim() === '') {
              continue;
            }
            row = row.replace('\r', '')
            const rowSplits = row.split(',');
            this.data[rowSplits[0]] = rowSplits;
          }
        } else {
          this.data = {};
        }
      });
  }

  headerSeleced(header) {
    this.selectedHeader = header;
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FileService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }

  public getHeaders() {
    return this.httpClient.get('assets/header.csv', { responseType: 'text' });
  }

  public getData() {
    return this.httpClient.get('assets/tableContent.csv', { responseType: 'text' });
  }
}
```

**sample html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h3>Headers</h3>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of headers"
      class="col-sm-3 bg-secondary p-2 m-1 text-white btn"
      (click)="headerSeleced(item)">
      {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
      <ng-container *ngIf="selectedHeader == item.key" >
        <div class="col-auto border">
          <b>{{item.key}}</b>
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="let prop of item.value" class="col-auto border">
          {{prop}}
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, You have given good approach, But I want to show data after click on particular heading of table. I don't want to load all data from tablecontent.csv. Suppose If I will click on myaccess the only myaccess data will come, If myaccess is not exist in tablecontent.csv the load should not populate.Can you update the answer, It will great help for me, Thanksss

Comment: Also a stackblitz verrsion https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zuncs7

Comment: Greate answer. Thanks

Comment: With your support, I achieved most of the functionality. I posted one more question. If you don't mind. Could you check.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62041235/how-to-set-data-of-table-down-to-particular-heading-in-table-using-angular

Comment: sure will do. Gimme 5

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'project';
  myData: any;
  myContent = [];
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClient.get('assets/header.csv', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.myData = data.split("\n");
      }
    );
  }
  clicked(event) {
    console.log(event.srcElement.name);
    this.httpClient.get('assets/tableContent.csv', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.myContent.push({event.srcElement.name: data.split(",")});
        let ab=this.myContent;
        console.log("------------>",ab);        
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Table heading will comes from header.csv and data will comes from tableContent.csv. So Finally If i will click on the particular header so It will search into json object(which is read by tablecontent.csv). will show the particular result. Like if I will click on the myAccess so related myaccess data show in the table data.

Comment: updated the solution, is it what you are looking for?

Comment: It is showing error on line    this.myContent.push({event.srcElement.name: data.split(",")});

Comment: you changed myContent to array like i did?

Comment: core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: @VSH you can check my answer it may help you out

Comment: @VSH set myContent = [] like i did above.

Comment: still issue is same

Comment: are you sure you have set myContent = [] and not resetting it any where? because push is normal method of an array.

Comment: oh, there was a mistake in had extra colon above. please check again and initialize it like that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the next line icon 
[image]

You need to add this line in your app.component.ts

```
this.httpClient.get('assets/content.csv', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
      data => {
             // add this line before the split
              data = data.replace(/[\r\n]/g,",");
             this.headerData = data.split(",").filter(Boolean);
      }
    );
```

First we will get the header data from CSV File

```
this.httpClient.get('assets/header.csv', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
      data => {
             // add this line before the split
              data = data.replace(/[\r\n]/g,",");
             this.headerData = data.split(",").filter(Boolean);
      }
    );
```

In order to get the desired output, you can split the array
according to your need. 
As guess from your CSV file image, column length will be now based on this.headerData.length which will be dynamic

```
 for( let index = 0; index < this.myContent.length; index ++) {
           const value = this.myContent.splice(0,this.headerData.length);
          // now you got the value you can create structure according to your need
 }
```

Read more about
[Array.Splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)  as it help allot while creating sub-array

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Column length will never fix

Comment: Great give me 5 min will update my answer according to it.